# Generating human readable bundle css and js files for reviewers

Tags: javascript, css

### Problem

I wrote a html file with many small JavaScript modules and CSS files for an Assignment.

But then I realized the reviewers wouldn't be able to review my solution correctly.

They expected students to write all CSS code in a single CSS file, and all JavaScript files in one file. In the HTML file refer to these files directly. Code without taking advantage of any features that can only run if the file is served by a server.

So that they can open the HTML file with a file manager directly in any browser.

#### Edit

I believe there is a legitimite need for generating human readable bundle files outside of this context.

For example:

Making a website's code completely human readable and verifiable in a browser by a user. This gives users the insight of whether they are running inspectable js code or just binary blobs. Yes, I can just ship it as is unbundled to them, but then there would be many round trips.

### Unsuccessful Solution 1: Module Bundlers

I then thought about using a module bundler to bundle all my files into one file of each type and generate the sourcemap for it.

But then the output bundle files are not human readable. A reviewer is certainly not going to be able to review the code in that.

They are also not going to use sourcemaps.

### Unsuccessful Solution 2: Concate the Files

Simply concating the files does not produce the correct output. Moreover, it is a hard problem to write a program that process and concat them correctly. It's basically a module bundler.

### Unsuccessful Solution 3: Use a Local Testing Server

Instruct the reviewers to start Python's HTTP Server by running `py -m http.server` then visit the directory at `localhost:8000`.

But then first I'm making things harder for them. Secondly this does not work because Python HTTP Server does not serve the MIME type of JavaScript files correctly by default. Sure there are [scripts](https://gist.github.com/HaiyangXu/ec88cbdce3cdbac7b8d5) but then I'm asking them to run unfamiliar code on their devices.

### Solution?

I think it's best to use something like a module bundler, but with human readable output.

#### Demo

##### Suppose I have following files in the directory src/demo:

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script defer type="module" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

index.css

```css
@import 'background-color.css';
```

background-color.css

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
```

index.js

```js
import './console-log.js';
```

console-log.js

```js
import { value } from './console-log-value.js';

console.log(value);
```

console-log-value.js

```js
export const value = 'a';
```

##### I want to generate files like this in the directory dist/demo:

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Tooling: The source directory is src/demo -->
<!-- Tooling: This file is generated from index.html -->

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

  <!-- Tooling: The attribute 'type=module' has to be removed from script tag. -->
  <!-- Tooling: Because JavaScript modules do not work if the file is opened directly. -->
  <script defer src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

index.css

```css
/* Tooling: The source directory is src/demo */
/* Tooling: This file is generated from index.css and background-color.css */

/* index.css */
/* @import 'background-color.css'; */

/* background-color.css */
body {
  background-color: black
}
```

index.js

```js
// Tooling: The source directory is src/demo
// Tooling: This file is generated from
// index.js, console-log.js by direct import,
// and console-log-value.js by importing member "value" in the module

// Tooling: Manually setting 'use strict'
// Tooling: Because JavaScript modules do not work if the file is opened directly,
// Tooling: the 'type=module' attribute of script tag is removed.
// Tooling: Therefore, 'use strict' has to be set manually.
'use strict';

// Tooling: index.js is placed before all other modules.
// Tooling: It is the entry point to all other modules.
// index.js
// import './console-log.js';

// Tooling: Creating new Block Scope
{
// Tooling: exported constants are placed at the top.
// console-log-value.js
const value = 'a';

// console-log.js
console.log(value);
}
```

#### How do I generate human readable bundle css and js files?

Comment: Yes, you could technically use a bundler with no minification options turned on.

Comment: If the expectation is for you "to write all CSS code in a single CSS file, and all JavaScript files in one file" why aren't you doing that? You seem to be really over-complicating the exercise that's been given to you.

Comment: @FranCarstens Of all the bundlers I have tried without minification options, the output is still not human readable code. I want something that is at least as readable as the demo in the question. Can you share your choice of bundler and the important configuration options?

Comment: @Andy I didn't know the expectation at the time I did the assignment. I later asked the reviewer and it is until then I got their expectation. Moreover, the reviewer's single JS file is more than 400 lines. I don't think that's a good way to do any development.

Comment: I'm going to agree with Andy here. I misread your 3rd paragraph. It would be significantly simpler to copy and paste the files appropriately. To make sure everything keeps working use CodePen or something similar.

Comment: @FranCarstens I have about 100 modules. Copy pasting the files would be pain. Moreover, the assignment is already due. I'm asking this question for getting the generated output files for further assignments. I expect these assignments to require more than 1000 lines of code if I write them in a single file so I'm trying to figure out how to do it using modules before giving up.

Comment: @rectangle, I think your approach to modern JS development is good, but this isn't what is being asked of you _right now_. The reviewer wants some readable CSS and JS, and you won't have that if you try to bundle/minimise your code. You should present the code as they want it, but also use some time to explain how you could do things a little differently. Sometimes listening is a great teaching tool.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the advice. But since the following assignments are much bigger than this one, it would take me a lot of time and headache if I can somehow successfully write all of the required code in a single file. And the result would be ugly and exceed 1000 lines or more. I really don't want to give up using modules, so that's why I am asking this question.

Comment: @Andy Also, I believe there is a legitimite for generating human readable bundle files outside of this context. In fact, I am considering making my website's code completely human readable in a browser by an user, and I don't want to present the users sourcemap. This gives users more control of whether they are running inspectable js code or just binary blobs. Yes, I can just ship it as is unbundled to them, but then there would be many round trips.

Comment: @rectangle but it doesn't matter. You've been asked to provide one CSS file, and one JS file. That's it. If you're one of many people who are submitting code to a reviewer, and they can't read your code, or understand it, or have to jump through many steps to decipher it, they will just stop reviewing it.

Comment: @Andy Thanks. I still hope there is a way to get a bundle with human readable code, though. If that can be acheived, then I don't have to give up using modules.

Comment: Just wanted to say that I hope your examples are actually just examples and your actual code modules aren't quite so pedantic. `console-log.js` and console-log-value.js` had me scratching my head in particular.

Comment: @Mordred Yes, of course. My examples in the question are really just examples. My actual code is not like that.